# Only allow one meta key value per post in a category

Tags: metabox, post-meta

I have created a meta box for a theme I am working on, it is a simple meta box with a check box for featured post. The problem is user can tick that check box for **multiple posts** in the **same category**.

I want to disable the meta value from an old post once a new post published under that category. So basically only allow 1 post to be checked as featured on any given category. I think I should do something with

```
delete_post_meta( $post_id, 'featured_post' );
```

but I am not sure how can I check previous posts and delete the post meta from them. Any suggestion?

**Update #1 :**

This is my meta box:

```
//FEATURED POST CHECK BOX

//ADD THE META BOX
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'add_featured_slide' );
function add_featured_slide(){
    //POST TYPES TO HAVE THE CUSTOM META BOX 
    $ctptypes = array( 'post', 'page', 'your_custom_post_type' );
    foreach ( $ctptypes as $ctptype ) {
        add_meta_box( 'featured-slide', 'Featured Post', 'featured_slide_func', $ctptype, 'side', 'high' );
    }
}
//DEFINE THE META BOX
function featured_slide_func( $post ){
    $values = get_post_custom( $post->ID );
    $check = isset( $values['special_box_check'] ) ? esc_attr( $values['special_box_check'][0] ) : '';
    wp_nonce_field( 'my_featured_slide_nonce', 'featured_slide_nonce' );
    ?>
    <p>
        <input type="checkbox" name="special_box_check" id="special_box_check" <?php checked( $check, 'on' ); ?> />
        <label for="special_box_check">Feature this post?</label>
    </p>
    <?php 
}
//SAVE THE META BOX DATA WITH THE POST
add_action( 'save_post', 'featured_slide_save' );
function featured_slide_save( $post_id ){
    if( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return;
    if( !isset( $_POST['featured_slide_nonce'] ) || !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['featured_slide_nonce'], 'my_featured_slide_nonce' ) ) return;
    if( !current_user_can( 'edit_post' ) ) return;
    $allowed = array( 
        'a' => array( 
            'href' => array() 
        )
    );
    // IF CHECKED SAVE THE CUSTOM META
    if ( isset( $_POST['special_box_check'] ) && $_POST['special_box_check'] ) {
        add_post_meta( $post_id, 'special_box_check', 'on', true );
    }
    // IF UNCHECKED DELETE THE CUSTOM META
    else {
        delete_post_meta( $post_id, 'special_box_check' );
    }
}
```

Comment: You should show us the code to display the meta box. BTW, a featured post is a `sticky post`, and it's a native function in WordPress. Why don't you use it? You can style the `.sticky` class if you are using the `post_class()` function to generate your post classes, which is the best practice.

Comment: @Gerard I updated the question

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to delete all meta values from all posts with this:

```
delete_metadata('post', null, $meta_key, null, true)
```

See the documentation which says, that the last argument is ment to delete all entries from all objects:

```
delete_metadata($meta_type, $object_id, $meta_key, $meta_value = '', $delete_all = false)
```

> $delete_all
>   (boolean) (optional) Optional, default is false. If true, delete
>   matching metadata entries for all objects, ignoring the specified
>   object_id. Otherwise, only delete matching metadata entries for the
>   specified object_id. Default: false

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/delete_metadata

Afterwards you can use `wp_get_recent_posts()` to get the latest post from a category and assign the meta value there.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_recent_posts

Comment: yes, but how can I make sure that only the last post in the given category has that meta?

Comment: your description is obscure in that point. so I added how you get the recent post to my answer

Answer (score 0):

You claim that you want to "..allow 1 post to be checked as featured on any given category." To do that you will need to associate your `special_box_check` with the categories rather than have a simple on/off toggle. That requires a change in the form where `$check` is set and `checked()` is used. It also requires a change to how the data is saved. Look for "Changes follow" in the source below.

```
//ADD THE META BOX
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'add_featured_slide' );
function add_featured_slide(){
    //POST TYPES TO HAVE THE CUSTOM META BOX 
    $ctptypes = array( 'post', 'page', 'your_custom_post_type' );
    foreach ( $ctptypes as $ctptype ) {
        add_meta_box( 'featured-slide', 'Featured Post', 'featured_slide_func', $ctptype, 'side', 'high' );
    }
}
//DEFINE THE META BOX
function featured_slide_func( $post ){
    $values = get_post_custom( $post->ID );
    $check = isset( $values['special_box_check'] ) ? true : false;
    wp_nonce_field( 'my_featured_slide_nonce', 'featured_slide_nonce' );
    ?>
    <p>
        <input type="checkbox" name="special_box_check" id="special_box_check" <?php checked( $check); ?> />
        <label for="special_box_check">Feature this post?</label>
    </p>
    <?php 
}
//SAVE THE META BOX DATA WITH THE POST
add_action( 'save_post', 'featured_slide_save', 10, 2 );
function featured_slide_save( $post_id, $post ){
    if( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return;
    if( !isset( $_POST['featured_slide_nonce'] ) || !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['featured_slide_nonce'], 'my_featured_slide_nonce' ) ) return;
    if( !current_user_can( 'edit_post' ) ) return;
    $allowed = array( 
        'a' => array( 
            'href' => array() 
        )
    );

    // Changes follow
    if ( isset( $_POST['special_box_check'] ) && $_POST['special_box_check'] ) {
        $cats = wp_get_post_categories($post_id);
        foreach ($cats as $v) {
          delete_metadata ( 'post', null, 'special_box_check', $v, true );
        }
        foreach ($cats as $v) {
          add_post_meta( $post_id, 'special_box_check', $v);
        }
    } else {
        delete_post_meta( $post_id, 'special_box_check' );
    }

}
```